# How to Clear rate of Ratingbar in Android?

Tags: android

I am new In android.
I Want to know the way of clear rating of ratingbar.

What should I Do?
[image]

Please Help Me...

Comment: ratingBar.setRating(0.0f); Hope it helps

Comment: This is useful for me... Thanks...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easy.

```
    RatingBar ratingBar = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
    ratingBar.setRating(0F);
```